# How to update AlexNet to use FCN? Confused on upsampling

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

The main issue is I don't understand how the upsampling works.  The AlexNet architecture has the following classifier

```
Dropout(),
Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096),
ReLU(),
Dropout(),
Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096),
ReLU(),
Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000)
```

The above is used on cifar so the num classes is 1000.  If we change the classifier to use FCN (following [FCN for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06211.pdf)) and use VOC we'll have 20 classes (why does the figure show 21 channels?). Images are resized to 256x256.  The architecture from the paper is shown below

[image: Figure 1]

Using pytorch I have the following

```
class AlexNetFCN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.features = AlexNet().features
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Dropout(),
                nn.Conv2d(256, 4096, kernel_size=6),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(),
                nn.Conv2d(4096, 4096, kernel_size=1),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(4096, 20, kernel_size=1),
                )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

I know after the feature portion my images are 7x7.  How do i upsample back up to 256x256?  Maybe `nn.Bilinear` but this isn't clear to me from the paper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nn.Upsample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html) layer, which is a wrapper around the [`nn.functional.interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate) function (old name is `nn.functional.upsample`)

Here's how it's used in a working alexnetfcn implementation:

https://github.com/monaj07/pytorch_semseg/blob/e93e96f811bcdb45c8c88380f561e87d0ccbf514/ptsemseg/models/fcn.py#L145